# How to create a shared library directory for multiple Java samples

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, shared-libraries

I have few different Java projects that uses the same libraries from Maven Repo, I have to manually download each library for each project. Is there a way that I can create a single directory and have all the XML library they depend on stored in the parent directory, so whenever I open a project, I can just go to Project Structure -> Libraries and import that directory? I'm using IntelliJ for these projects. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use Maven for your projects, all the libraries will be stored in .m2 directory and shared between all your projects.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the tip! the reason why I want it that way is whenever someone downloads those projects, they can easily access those libraries by just importing that directory that stores those libraries.

Comment: Maven will download the libraries for them automatically.